# How to use a component for different paths with different data loaded for this component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a component.

```
<template>
      <HotTable :settings="hotSettings" ></HotTable>
</template>

<script>
import HotTable from "@handsontable/vue";
import Handsontable from "handsontable";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        hotSettings: {
          data: 
          [
            ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2016", "10", 11, 12, 13],
            ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ],
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: true
        }
    };
  },
  components: {
    HotTable
  }
};
</script>
```

This component is displayed in three different ways: `/path/path1`, `/path/path2`, `/path/path3`. How can I make it so that, when navigating these paths, this component is displayed on each page, but the data for it (the `data` field) would be different?

Recently suggested to use `props` in the routes.

My component

```
<template>
  <HotTable :data="myData"></HotTable>
</template>

<script>
import HotTable from "@handsontable/vue";
import Handsontable from "handsontable";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {}
    };
  },
  props: ["myData"],
  components: {
    HotTable
  }
};
</script>

<style src="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"></style>
<style>
#hot-preview {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Route file

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: '/tables/groups',
      component: Table,
      props: {
        myData: [
          ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
          ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
          ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 14],
          ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 15]
        ]
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/tables/subjects',
      component: Table,
      props: {
        myData: [
          ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
          ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 15],
          ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 14],
          ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
        ]
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

This solution is working, but I need to get the data for the table dynamically, so I'm using the store. How can I associate a store with this construct?

File `store.js`

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    groupsTableData: [],
  },
  actions: {
    loadGroupsTableData({commit}) {
      axios
        .get("/api/tables/groups")
        .then((response) => {
          commit("SET_GROUPS_TABLE_DATA", response.data);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_GROUPS_TABLE_DATA(state, data) {
      state.groupsTableData = data;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    groupsTableData: state => {
      return state.groupsTableData
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Structure `groupsTableData` to be a key value store. The key will be the id specific table and value will be the data associated to that table. Then you use the getter to fetch the data for the specific data table using the id.